# Neo4j and big log files

Tags: database, nosql, neo4j

I try to use n4j in my app, but I have problem with big log files. Are they necessary or is there some way to reduce the number and size of them?

At the moment I see files like:

> nioneo_logical.log.v0
>
> nioneo_logical.log.v1
>
> nioneo_logical.log.v2

etc
and they are ~26MB each (over 50% of neo4j folder).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These files are created whenever the logical logs are rotated.

You can configure rules for them in the server properties file.

See details here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-logical-logs.html

You can safely remove them (but only the *.v*) if your database is shutdown and in a clean state. Don't remove them while the db is running because they could be needed in case of recovery on a crash.

Comment: Please note that with the upcoming release 2.2 of Neo4j, the logfiles will be renamed to neostore.transaction.db.vXXX.

See: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/kernel/CHANGES.txt